# Porque tiene que ir datatype html siempre que voy a editar

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap

Mi pregunta es porque debemos poner un datatype igual a html si lo que voy a enviar solo es un id acaso no se puede enviar en json,,me podrian explicar ese codeigo??

```js
$(".btn-edit-marcas").on('click',   function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var _id =$(this).attr('id');

        if(confirm("Deseas |modificar este registro?jjh")){
                //  alert(_id);
                $('#btn-add-marca').attr("disabled", true);

  $.ajax({
   url: baseURL +'marcas/action_edit',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'html',
   data: {
    id:_id
   },
  })
  .done(function(response) {

   console.log(response)
   $('#result').html(response) ;
  })
  .fail(function(response) {
   console.log("error",response);
  })

        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataType` indica a `JQuery` el tipo de **respuesta** que esperamos del servidor, la cual puede ser `xml`, `html`, `script`, `json`, `jsonp`, `text` o `múltiple`, para mas información leer la documentación de [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Por lo que no es necesario usar siempre `html`, todo depende de las necesidades de tu proyecto.

En cambio `contentType` es la cabecera que le indica al servidor el tipo de **datos que estamos enviando**, que por default es `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`